# Virtual function mechanism

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class T {
public:
    virtual int f(int x) { cout << "T::f" << endl; return 0; }
    void g() { f(1); cout << "T::g" << endl; }
    virtual void h() { g(); cout << "T::h" << endl; }
};

class S: public T {
public:
    int f(double y) { cout << "S::f" << endl; return 2; }
    virtual void g() { f(1); cout << "S::g" << endl; }
    virtual void h() { g(); cout << "S::h" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    T t; S s; T * p = &s;
    p -> f(1.5);
    p -> g();
    p -> h();
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused about which functions exactly will be executed, even though I have read about virtual function mechanism in several textbooks. Any help will be highly appreciated.

*Update*: I have run the code and the output is:

```
T::f
T::f
T::g
S::f
S::g
S::h
```

I can't understand how we choose which functions will be executed when we are already inside of a function, for instance.

Comment: Did you try running this code? Can you be more specific about what confuses you?

Comment: compile, run, and see?

Comment: I should be prepared to know this without compiling program.

Answer (score 1):

In your class T will be silently created pointer to virtual table of functions (you can find it exists if you will call sizeof(T), it will be bigger at sizeof(void*) then have to). Your class S will also have such pointer to another virtual table.

Such virtual table have just pointers to functions.

When your class S created, it makes copy of virtual table from T. And then replace pointers to functions defined at T by pointers to functions defined as S. So, it will not replace pointer to function f(), because you don't define it in S, but it will replace pointer to function h(), because you redefined it in S.

So, when you get object with virtual table when first pointer points to T::f(), and second points to S::h(). And you try to operate with that object as with object T.

So, when you call f() - you receive as if T::f() was called.
When you call h() - you receive as if S::h() was called.

Method without "virtual" don't inputs to this table. So, T* will now know about virtual method that was added in child class, and T* will call it's own virtual method if it was not redefined in object.

That is all.